# cqlsh :: ImportError: cannot import name cql_keywords_reserved

Tags: python, cassandra, pip, cqlsh

Recently, I have installed `Cassandra. 3.6`
After installation,  I got an error.

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})
```

To solve this, I have followed

```
pip install cassandra-driver==2.7.2
pip install cassandra-driver
export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
```

And my python version is `2.7`

right Now, when I run `cqlsh`, I'm getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 167, in <module>
    from cqlshlib import cql3handling, cqlhandling, pylexotron, sslhandling
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlshlib/cql3handling.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .cqlhandling import CqlParsingRuleSet, Hint
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cqlshlib/cqlhandling.py", line 21, in <module>
    from cassandra.metadata import cql_keywords_reserved
ImportError: cannot import name cql_keywords_reserved
```

How can I solve this error? How can I run cassandra withour errors?

Comment: `pip install cassandra-driver==3.7.1` ? or install python 2.7.11 (or less) http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/08/16/cqlsh-broken-on-fresh-installs.html The error is because cqlsh in 3.7 is using api's in the python drivers 3 branch

Comment: @ChrisLohfink . I tried with cassandra driver. Still have the same error

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing [CASSANDRA-11840](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850), which occurs with older versions of the driver with Python 2.7.12+.

To work around it, either

1.) Upgrade to Cassandra 3.8+, which bundles a driver version that does not have this problem.

or

2.) Make your environment/PATH use Python <= 2.7.11

or

3.) CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=1 as you guessed, but install a version of the driver that has the fix (cassandra-driver >= 3.4.0).

Comment: I have followed your first option. I'm still getting another error.

Comment: `Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

Comment: That usually indicates that Cassandra is not running.

Comment: Are you asking me how to start Cassandra? That depends entirely on how you installed it. Each of the methods described [here](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html) have a step for starting the service.